# Errors when Generating Devise Views

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, haml, devise, bundler

I am developing a rails 3 application and I am using Devise for authentication.  Everything seems to be working just fine, but when I try to generate the views using **rails generate devise:views**, I get a bunch of errors like this:

```
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.2/lib/bundler/shared_helpers.rb:2:in `require': no such file to load -- rubygems (LoadError)
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.2/lib/bundler/shared_helpers.rb:2
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.2/lib/bundler/setup.rb:1:in `require'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.2/lib/bundler/setup.rb:1
```

My default template engine is HAMl and I have the hpricot gem installed (as it says to do on the Devise github page).

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that it had something to do with my gems being stored in a different location than ruby.  I'm not sure why it suddenly became a problem with that particular command.  But re-installing rubygems seemed to do the trick.

Comment: Which gems did you need to re-install?

Comment: What were the two paths? Was one of them the system path?

Answer (score 1):

Give it a shot with `bundle exec`:

```
bundle exec rails g devise:views
```